# Mapbox sidepanel and polygon interaction

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am attempting to make an interaction between images in a sidepanel and polygons on a map, so when the sidepanel is moved via mousescroll, the corresponding polygon with same name is brought into focus.

My [current attempt](http://divdesign.biz/freelancer/randolfnewmap/neigh/) is not responsive to mousescrolls as needed. Is there another approach than the one I have taken?

```
   $('.sidebar').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
   $("#help").html(' ');
   var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
   var $imgs = $('.sidebar').find('img');
   var $midElement;
   var distance = null;
   var currDistance = 0;
   var minHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
   var maxHeight = $(window).height();

   var img_h=$('.sidebar').find('img');
   var img_h1=img_h.height() / 2;

    var middleHeightA = (maxHeight + minHeight) / 2;
    var middleHeight = middleHeightA - img_h1;  
    $.each($imgs, function() {

    currDistance = Math.abs(middleHeight - $(this).position().top);
if ( distance == null || currDistance < distance ) {
    /*$midElement = $(element);*/
    distance = currDistance;
        for (j=0;j<polygons1.length;j++) {
            polygons1[j].setStyle({color: '#fff',fillColor:'#000', weight:'1px'});
        }

    var scrid=$(this).attr('id');
        for (j=0;j<help.length;j++) {
            id=help[j];
            if(id==scrid)
            {               
               polygons1[j].openPopup(polygons1[j].getBounds().getCenter());    
               map.setView(polygons1[j].getBounds().getCenter(),10);
               polygons1[j].setStyle({color: '#e72f2a',fillColor:'#e72f2a',weight:'7px'});
              $('.thumbnail').removeClass('active');
              $('.'+scrid).addClass('active');                 
            }
        }
}



    var scrid=$(this).attr('id');
        for (j=0;j<help.length;j++) {
            id=help[j];
            if(id==scrid)
            {               
               polygons1[j].openPopup(polygons1[j].getBounds().getCenter());    
               map.setView(polygons1[j].getBounds().getCenter(),10);
               polygons1[j].setStyle({color: '#e72f2a',fillColor:'#e72f2a',weight:'7px'});
            }
        }       
}*/
```

Comment: It seems to work (that is, the various features will be highlighted as you scroll past them with the mousewheel) in Chrome 49.0.2623.110. It's a little bit jumpy, since it refocuses every time the mousewheel moves, but it does respond.

Comment: thanks. I wonder what I am missing so the behavior is faster, more fluid.

Comment: It seems like the jumpiness arises from calling `setView` and `openPopup` too often. Do you actually run your for loop with the highlighting routines twice, or is that a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use a `debounce` function. Debounce function limits the rate at which a function can fire. The idea is to make polygons focus not every time a mouse-wheel event is triggered, but focus them with a kind of *cooldown*.

Debounce functions are already implemented in many libraries, for example in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce). All you have to do is to wrap your `mousewheel` callback in it. Something like:

```
$('.sidebar').bind('mousewheel', _.debounce(function(e){
   $("#help").html(' '); 
   ... 
), 100});
```

Pay attention to `options` param, in lodash implementation, most probably you would like to use one of them, for example `maxWait`.